# Traversal using UP and DOWN arrow keys - Handling Button's FocusOut

Tags: java, events, user-interface, swt

what i am trying to archive here is to traverse within controls using the UP and DOWN arrow keys
the code goes something like this in the display object. Might seem strange but this is a requirement :-/

```
displayObj.addFilter(SWT.KeyDown,new Listener() {
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        Control ctrl= (Control) event.widget;
        if(event.keyCode==SWT.ARROW_UP) {                   
            ctrl.traverse(SWT.TRAVERSE_TAB_PREVIOUS);
        } else if(event.keyCode==SWT.ARROW_DOWN) {
            ctrl.traverse(SWT.TRAVERSE_TAB_NEXT);
        }
    }
});
```

this works fine for the texts and combo boxes. But the third field is a Button (`compositeObj,SWT.CHECK`) at which point this doesn't work because a `SWT.FocusOut` event is generated and the focus moves to the next button 'OK' 'Cancel' instead of the combobox that sits immediately afterwards. The tab traversal correctly happens in correct order as in text, text, button , combo , button and button.
Cannot use a `FocusListener`  because there is no way to handle the UP and DOWN arrow events separately.

Are there any other ways of doing this?. Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: Your widget ordering is correct and traversal works as expected if you use tab?  That is to say, if you tab out of the checkbox `Button`, you go to the combo and not the OK button?

Comment: Yes tabbing out of the checkbox goes to the combo not the okay button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using TraverseListener as shown below on the buttons solved the problem.

```
cancelButton.addTraverseListener(new TraverseListener () {
public void keyTraversed(TraverseEvent e) {
e.doit=false;
if (e.keyCode==16777218) {
userIdText.forceFocus();
} else if (e.keyCode==16777217) {
connectButton.forceFocus();
}
else {
//do nothing,i guess;
}
}
});
```

Thanks anyway.